# What is the speed at which the driver appears to approach the truck?

Tags: reflection, relative-motion

The rear view mirror of a car is a plane mirror.A driver is reversing his car at a speed of 2m/s.The driver sees in his rear view mirror the image of the truck parked behind the car.The speed at which the image of the truck appear to approach the driver will be ?

In this case the mirror is on move with the driver so the image should come closer by the same distance moved by the car but so is not the case as mentioned in my textbook.

Thanks.

*

Comment: You might want to include the statement from your text.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The image is initially in front of the driver - that is where it appears when the driver looks in the mirror.

You are right - the image gets closer to the driver by 2m/sec.

But the driver is moving backwards at 2m/sec.

As far as the world outside is concerned the image moves backwards at 4m/sec.

Comment: Shouldn't it be that the image approaches the object at the speed of 4 m/s and not the driver?

Comment: Yes, that is what happens, and you explain it well, but the question was about the driver.